# error in solution about measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

How is inequality strict in a set that is after coloured on yellow equality (last line)? I think that is a mistake since $f_n$ could equal $f$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the equal sign you highlighted must be replaced by the inclusion $\supset$. Then the proof is valid and we can still conclude.

Comment: then the inequality would be in other direction than desired

Comment: No it is in the correct direction, look at the statement you want to prove.

Comment: yeah, my bad, thank you